# How to color plot by a mixture of multiple colors?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Working in numpy and matplotlib.

Suppose I have some data `y` and multiple (say I have 4) other data `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4` which are all 1 x n datasets. Further suppose that the elements of the `p` data all add up to 1 (element wise), in other words `p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == np.ones(n)` is `True`.

My question is, how can I plot `y` and make the colors of the data points be some combination according to the `p` data? So, say I choose blue, green, yellow, and red. If an element in `p1` is 0, it should be white, if it is 1 it should be blue. `p2` will correspond to red, etc... But, I want the final color to be a mixture of all 4 colors, according to the weights specified in the `p` vectors.

I'm having a hard time articulating myself, so let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Linear combination of 4 colours is possible. However, it will be likely that some different combinations of `p1,p2,p3,p4` can have the same colour. Would that be what you expect?

Comment: As an example of what you want to achieve, I think the following samples will help.[Multicolored lines](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py) & [Color by y-value](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/color/color_by_yvalue.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-by-yvalue-py)

Comment: I guess my main struggle lies in the mixture of the colors. I know how to color lines by data, but I don't know how to create the color data such that is is a proper mixture of a finite number of colors.